# One or several tag repositories for my site?

Tags: content-search

I have a Sitecore 9.0.2 site that contains a list of shops that are currently only searchable by shop name. We wish to improve the search feature by tagging up shops with:

1. Product categories (e.g. shampoo, socks ...)
2. Brands (e.g. Levis, Nestlé ...)

We wish to be able to create hierarchies and related tags within product categories. For example, "chocolate" would be a child of "sweets", and a user searching for "chocolate" might see all shops with the parent "sweets" tag or even any sibling tags such as "winegums".

The question: Would you place the product category tags and the brand tags in the same tag repository? Or would you keep two types of tags separate?
I ask because Sitecore seems to support having multiple tag repositories. I just don't know what the best practice is.

Comment: Are you using Sitecore Experience Commerce?

Comment: Nope, we are talking the basic CMS (Experience Platform I guess).

Comment: How are you going to use this tags? From the technical perspective? Do you build own search queries? 
So if you have a full control on search logic - you even can build a tags in any way as you want. From my experience, some clients expects to manage all tags in one place, some clients don't like it. All depends of your requirements. I don't see any best practices here.

Comment: With each shop being an item in Sitecore, we plan to tag the shop item with tags in the sitecore tag repository (or repositories). The users will create those tags manually in Sitecore. We are in control of the underlying search logic. The customer, like me, doesn't know much about tagging and doesn't have an opinion on the matter.